# How can I view full URLs in Chrome history?

Tags: google-chrome, history

I use Chrome 78.0.3904.97 on Windows 10.

There is a "History" menu option that lists previously visited pages. It shows the page title and the domain name, but not the full URL.

How can I view the full URLs, without actually clicking to visit each page?

Comment: See if this app works for you>>>>https://betanews.com/2017/03/06/three-ways-to-inspect-google-chrome-history/

Comment: I tried SterJo Chrome History program and it works with current version of Chrome.

Comment: Go to `chrome://history/`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you press `Ctrl + H` Chrome will open a tab that contains the Webpage title and the main URL of the website
And if you right click on the link wich interessts you A bloc will pop up you ll dind `Copy link adress` Then just paste it in notepad or anywhere else and you ll obtain the full URL

Comment: It is not very convenient to click them one at a time -- I'm not sure why Chrome can't just display a list of URLs -- but it does work. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

This works on Chrome Desktop Version 104.0.5112.81 (Official Build) (64-bit):

```
[...document.querySelector("#history-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#history").shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("history-item").entries()]
.map(_ => _[1].shadowRoot.querySelector("#link>div").style['background-image'])
.map(_ => decodeURIComponent(_.match(/page_url=(?<url>[^;]+?)&allow_google_server_fallback/).groups.url))
//.filter(_ => _.startsWith('https://SomeDomain.com/PathOfInterest'))
.forEach(_ => console.log(_))
```

Comment: Since its not an answer, maybe you should delete it to avoid downvotes

Comment: I was planning to revisit this topic soon with the real answer once I figured it out...which I just did.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Awesome. It is mindboggling how utterly useless the current history list in Chrome is. The query did not work today (version 121.0.6167.189), but needed an update which is simpler: `Array.from(document.querySelector("#history-app").shadowRoot.querySelector("#history").shadowRoot.querySelectorAll("history-item")).map(_ => _.shadowRoot.querySelector('.website-link')).forEach(a => console.log(a.href))`.

Answer (score 0):

I was looking for the same solution so I can trim some type-ahead results from the omnibox.
If you hover over the page icon for each result, you can see the full url and then act accordingly.
In Chrome 116+ (and possibly before) you can view the history search results by "group", which DOES then show the full URL.

Comment: FYI, when you switch from "By date" to "By group" in the Chrome History tab, Chrome will "condense" the pages/URLs it displays. That is, it no longer displays the full history... it decides to toss out some items. Apparently URLs that only differ in their query string parameters will be "grouped" into a single URL. That's not helpful for my use case!